# REGEX: Exclude matches after a specific string

Tags: regex

So I am trying to get the token that starts with a `3`.

The `AAXX` line below is picking it up right. However, doing some edge cases, the wrong 3 token is getting picked up in the `BBXX` line. The difference is that in `BBXX` line, the 3 group appears after a `222\d{2}` token.

This `222\d{2}` token is optional. I will only want the 3 token that appears before it, never after it. And even then, the 3 token is optional and might not appear.

So basically, want the optional token that begins with `3` that either appears before `222\d{2}` if it exists, or before the end of the line if it doesn't.

I don't know if that requires a negative look behind, or just how to exclude a match that would start with `222\d{2}`.

https://regex101.com/r/MOgfl8/1

Thanks.

Comment: Is this for PCRE? Please mention tool/lang you're using. In PCRE you can exclude the part by using [`(*SKIP)(*F)` technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex). Eg for your task something like: [`\b222\d.*(*SKIP)(*F)|3\d{4}`](https://regex101.com/r/tGTxp6/1)

Answer (score 1):

This answer assumes that you can accept using a capture group for the `333` number to be matched.  We can use a negative lookahead with tempered dot here:

```
^((?!\b222\d+).)*(3\d{4})
```

### Demo

This pattern says to match:

```
^                 from the start of the line
((?!\b222\d+).)*  match all content WITHOUT crossing over a 222x number
(3\d{4})          match and capture in \1 a 3x number
```

Comment: Demo link looks to be broken.

Comment: I made the first part non capturing, and it looks like this will work. Thank you so much.